# Regular Expressions: Search in list in python3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, list

I have a list of strings.

Consider the code below:

```
import re
mylist = ["http://abc/12345?abc", "https://abc/abc/2516423120?$abc$"]
r = re.compile("(\d{3,})")

result0 = list(filter(r.findall, mylist))  # Note 1
print(result0)

result1 = r.findall(mylist[0])
result2 = r.findall(mylist[1])
print(result1, result2)
```

The results are:

```
['http://abc/12345?abc', 'https://abc/abc/2516423120?$abc$']

['12345'] ['2516423120']
```

Why is there a difference in the results we get?

[Code snippet](https://rextester.com/WFZ2396)

Comment: `filter` is just checking if the elements match the regex, not returning the results of findall. With map instead of filter, the results would be the same

Comment: `filter` just passes expression to `findall` and since it returns a non empty list, filter lets the _original text_ pass.

Comment: Ok I get it now! Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you expected `filter` to do, but what it does here is that it returns an iterator over all elements `x` of `mylist` for which `bool(r.findall(x))` is `False`. This is only the case if `r.findall(x)` returns an empty list, i.e. the regex does not match the string, so here `result0` contains the same values as `mylist`.